# VSCode settings for search paths with PEP582 & ipykernel

Tags: visual-studio-code, pep

I used python package managers (PyFlow/PDM) which supports [PEP582](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0582/): packages are installed in the local directory `{workspace_path}/__pypackages__/`.

I added some configs in `settings.json` to let VSCode know how to find the packages:

```json
{
  ...,
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "__pypackages__/3.7lib"
  ],
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "__pypackages__/3.7/lib"
  ]
}
```

I wrote some code, and the completion and inline code docs works well with above settings.

```py
# main.py
#%% jupyter cell
import sys
print(sys.path)
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)
#%% 
print("hello world")
```

I ran my `main.py` in both ways:

- Run the file with VSCode (`ctrl + opt + N`)
- Run the [jupyter cell with ipykernel](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py#_jupyter-code-cells) (`shift + enter`). VSCode asked me to install ipykernel at the first time, but it installed with `pip`, and not installed into `__pypackages__`.

but it failed and showed: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`.

I check the search path with `sys.path`, it doesn't contain `__pypackages__` for python modules:

```py
['{$HOME}/{workspace}',
 '{$HOME}/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.5.745244803/pythonFiles',
 '{$HOME}/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.5.745244803/pythonFiles/lib/python',
 '{$HOME}/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/lib/python37.zip',
 '{$HOME}/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/lib/python3.7',
 '{$HOME}/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '{$HOME}/{workspace}/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '{$HOME}/{workspace}/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '{$HOME}/.ipython']
```

My questions:

- How to configure `settings.json` to add search paths (`__pypackages__/3.7lib`) for Python modules.
- How to configure `settings.json` to let VSCode Jupyter server launch IPython with ipykernel installed in `__pypackages__/3.7lib`

Answer (score 6):

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/__pypackages__/<major.minor>/lib"
    ],
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/__pypackages__/<major.minor>/lib"
    ],
```

Try this in settings.json

Replace <major.minor> with your python version like 3.10, 3.9, etc

Answer (score 1):

I found two ways to solve the `sys.path` problem.

The easiest one would be to launch VSCode with the following command:

```
pdm run -p <path-to-profile> code <path-to-folder-or-workspace-file>
```

This ensures that PYTHONPATH contains `__packages__\...` directories for VSCode to use.